# How to get data from Firestore at Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am new at Flutter and Firebase, I just want to fetch data from Firestore, for example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG1jv.png), I just want to fetch the value of "KullaniciAdi" from the "11@gmail.com" document, as simply as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the structure of the folders is confusing, in general the documents are IDs, like this:

Example:

Collection (users) - Document (sALkf983l3j5RGjsk82lfds) - Fields (name, email, gender)

In this case you could make a call like this:

```
final FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

final DocumentSnapshot docUser =
          await firestore.collection('users').doc('sALkf983l3j5RGjsk82lfds').get();
```

You can do it:

```
final FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

final DocumentSnapshot docUser =
          await firestore.collection('KullaniciAdi').doc('11@gmail.com').get();
```

Editing:

To fetch a specific field value:

```
 final ref =  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .doc('users/$userId').get();
    final value = ref.get('name');
```

Comment: Thanks, but i am stuck at fetch data from a selected "field". For example where should i put the field parameter? Inside of "get()" or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: viewDetails(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data!.docs.length; i++) {
              if (snapshot.data!.docs[i].id == "11@gmail.com") {
                final DocumentSnapshot e = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
                dersiniz = "${e["Dersiniz"]}";
                return Center(child: Text(dersiniz),);
                
                
                
              }
            }
          },
          )


static Stream<QuerySnapshot> viewDetails() {
    CollectionReference notesItemCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("KullaniciAdi");

    return notesItemCollection.snapshots();
  }
```

used like this

Comment: Thanks for share, but when i use this code i am getting "This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled." errors, because of exclamation mark at "snapshot.data!". And the fix i find for this error is upgrading "sdk" at "pubspec.yaml. But when i upgrade sdk i am getting multiple errors even from most simple codes, for example, getting an error called ("Non-nullable instance field 'ders' must be initialized.") because of defining a "string" variable. And many more. I can't believe fetching data from a field of a database is that complicated.